# Refusing connection to POP3 server on Debian 6

Tags: debian, postfix, debian-squeeze, courier

I have installed `Postfix` and `Courier` on my VPS server based on `Debian Squeeze`. My server uses `MySQL` database.

Every daemon works properly, but I cannot login to my account using neither POP3 nor IMAP.
IceDove (Thunderbird) on my desktop says: Username or password invalid, but I'm sure that both username and password are correct. I have checked it many times, I have been changing password many times and the result is always the same. Some time ago I installed mail server with similar configuration on other server. The only difference was that I didn't use **SSL**.

I have tried to send email to set address by `mailx` and it was delivered correctly. (I've checked it in mail directory).

In my `/var/log/mail.log` I have:

```
Jul 21 09:18:00 kolodziej pop3d: Connection, ip=[::ffff:46.113.168.72]
Jul 21 09:18:01 kolodziej postfix/smtpd[6357]: cannot load Certificate Authority data: disabling TLS support
Jul 21 09:18:01 kolodziej postfix/smtpd[6357]: warning: TLS library problem: 6357:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:bss_file.c:126:fopen('/etc/postfix/cacert.pem','r'):
Jul 21 09:18:01 kolodziej postfix/smtpd[6357]: warning: TLS library problem: 6357:error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:bss_file.c:129:
Jul 21 09:18:01 kolodziej postfix/smtpd[6357]: warning: TLS library problem: 6357:error:0B084002:x509 certificate routines:X509_load_cert_crl_file:system lib:by_file.c:274:
Jul 21 09:18:01 kolodziej postfix/smtpd[6357]: connect from user-46-113-168-72.play-internet.pl[46.113.168.72]
Jul 21 09:18:01 kolodziej pop3d: LOGOUT, ip=[::ffff:46.113.168.72]
Jul 21 09:18:01 kolodziej pop3d: Disconnected, ip=[::ffff:46.113.168.72]
Jul 21 09:18:02 kolodziej postfix/smtpd[6357]: improper command pipelining after EHLO from user-46-113-168-72.play-internet.pl[46.113.168.72]
Jul 21 09:18:02 kolodziej postfix/smtpd[6357]: disconnect from user-46-113-168-72.play-internet.pl[46.113.168.72]
```

Comment: The log you've provided doesn't show anything about why pop3d's authentication is failing (that's probably in /var/log/auth.log), but it is showing a problem with SMTP:

Jul 21 09:18:01 kolodziej postfix/smtpd[6357]: warning: TLS library problem: 6357:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:bss_file.c:126:fopen('/etc/postfix/cacert.pem','r'):

It can't find the certificate file you've specified. Perhaps you have a permissions issue or path error, and perhaps there is a similar issue with your pop3d config?

Answer (score 1):

It's trying to connect over TLS (a secure connection like HTTPS) and for this it has to find a certificate file and read it.

It's probably a permissions error on your /etc/postfix/cacert.pem file. Check that file can be read by whatever user is running postfix (it might be a service account).

Also, are you perhaps connecting on the wrong port (e.g. a TLS without SSL, or non-secure POP3 (or IMAP))? Check what ports you are connecting to:

```
IMAP4/SSL                  993 (TCP)
IMAP4 with or without TLS  143 (TCP)    
POP3/SSL                   995 (TCP)    
POP3 with or without TLS   110 (TCP)
```